# Not getting value of Team Bot Isback

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have been trying to show some information to user on clicking button of my bot.

```
var card = new HeroCard
{
    Title = "Welcome to Covid-19 Tracker",
    Text = "Type 'help' to see what bot can do?",
    Subtitle = "Know more about Covid-19.",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>
    { 
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "How it spreads?", value: "spread"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.MessageBack, "Symptoms" , value: "Symptom"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.MessageBack, "Prevention Guidelines" , value: "Prevention")
    },
};
```

When i am clicking on these button from emulator i am able to read the value to property but when i am deploying it to Teams, value is coming as {}.
I am retrieving value using below code.

```
turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do? Does "Isback" mean imBack? If so, why aren't any of your card actions imBack actions? Are you trying to use imBack or a different kind of action?

Comment: Kyle, earlier i was using ImBack but i don't want user to see message passed to i tried using PostBack and MessageBack although both of them are not working when deployed to teams.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mark it  correct, It worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Teams does not support `postBack` as a distinct action type from `messageBack` so it will interpret `postBack` and `messageBack` the same way. You can see the four properties you can use in a `messageBack` action [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#messageback).

Your action isn't working in Teams because you're trying to use a string for the value property. If you want to keep using a string then you can use the text property like Sandeep suggested, and then your bot will have to read the text from the incoming activity's text property instead of its value property. If you want to keep using the value property then you should use an object instead of a string like this:

```
new CardAction(ActionTypes.MessageBack, "Prevention Guidelines", value: new { choice: "Prevention" })
```

This would populate the value property of the incoming activity with that same object, so you could access the user's selection like this:

```
var selection = turnContext.Activity.Value is null ? null : (JToken.FromObject(turnContext.Activity.Value) as JObject)?["choice"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Behavior of cards differs for different channels, in some cases value of card action is posted back to bot and in other cases text of card action (noticed this difference between webchat and msTeams channels). I would suggest one of the below step, it worked for me

1. Add text property in card action
2. or change ActionTypes to ActionTypes.ImBack

Comment: I don't want the user to see the message sent to bot. Is it possible with ImBack?